# My Ubuntu MX4 is frozen after installing xubuntu-desktop with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a MEIZU MX4 Ubuntu edition cellphone, I wanted to open a GUI from my mac to this devices, and I installed xubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xdrp
sudo reboot
```

Very bad things happened!

My device froze! The screen is black, and `adb` shell can't connect to it.

I have tried to to recover using recovery mode. While holding down the home button and volume, the phone display a logo of ubuntu, and I can enter `adb` shell, but apt-get can't be run:

```
 /sbin/sh: apt-get: not found
```

What can I do?

---

6.4 new
My dear friends, I come back. 
Today I have tried :ubuntu-device-flash,but unluckly.

Someone tell me :

```
 ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/meizu.en --recovery-image recovery.img --bootstrap
```

and :

```
  ubuntu-device-falsh -v touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/meizu.en --recovery-image recovery.img --bootstrap
```

When files downloaded, My ubuntu host is freezen!

---------23:44 asia/shanghai------
That I have a problem operation to enter fastboot mode.
that's ok now!
thanks.

---

At last,I think this pictures can help other people.

[image: Flash process]

[image]
<sup>**Flash process is freezing**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**frozen phone picture**</sup>

Comment: You tried to install another desktop on it? This sounds crazy, I like it! :P 

On the bq you can reboot in Recovery mode by pressing for like 30s Vol up + Power button.

Comment: haha~  yes ,i have tried to enter recovery mode, press power and vol up buttons,  But it does not make any sense. thanks for you edit my question . Easy to understand.

Comment: What about to reboot into the bootloader by pressing the correct physical button combination for MX4 (For nexus 4 it's Vol down + Power)
and then installing ubun tu by this way  : https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Comment: Very disappointed,Failure，MX4 can't enter this mode. when I tried to press the Vol down and Power, the phone auto restarted.

Comment: Ya, I can't find the right combination to go into bootloader mode for MX4 on internet. don't enevn know if bootlodaer is unlock on MX4 ubuntu (hope so)
Will let you know if I find something (Maybe try Vol down + central button + power or some others combination)

And I don't know at all if reinstalling ubuntu from bootloader is available on MX4. 
Hope someone will find a way to solve it

Comment: thank you very much , The BL is locked, It may be no way out. Tomorrow I will contect to meizu factroy,

Comment: Maybe if you don't have more things to lose, you could try the "Unlock the Android device" section in my  previous link. 
Using the command "sudo fastboot oem unlock" but few chances for working with meizu I think. 
It doesn't make sense to me that Meizu locked his BL on MX4 ubuntu.

Comment: dear alexadre, I come back.

Answer (score 7):

The following Q&A from David Planella implies that you probably should never change your device to RW-mode if you don't have complete control over a mobile device to flash an image:

- [How to change the Ubuntu installation to read-write mode on a mobile device](https://askubuntu.com/q/380258/40581)

---

**Your phone is not a desktop**. Installing desktop specific packages may break the configuration of your phone (similar to how non-desktop packages can break your desktop installation). You also shouldn't use apt-get on the phone unless you are fully aware of the consequences, which the average desktop user typically is not.

From a developer perspective you would just flash a working image from the image server to an unlocked phone. However for a normal consumer there isn't always an option to buy an unlocked or unlockable phone (`fastboot oem unlock` is specific to Google's Nexus devices). So you can't correct mistakes like above yourself and the device manufacturers **customer service may charge you** and require to send your device in **for servicing**.

Regarding apt-get being unavailable on recovery, this is probably how it is supposed to be. apt-get is not a vital part of the Android or Ubuntu Phone/Snappy infrastructure, so it shouldn't be surprising that it isn't included in the recovery image, which is different from the recovery mode on the desktop.

Remember that you are on the phone and you get updates through OTA images or the store. You also shouldn't use apt-get, since you would need to reinstall and configure all packages again after an OTA update, this is how the phone works: apt-get is available but not guaranteed to work like on the desktop. I also doubt that the store offered you this package for installation.

One thing you could try is to the read the system logs if these are available from the recovery or even do exist and try to find out what keeps the phone from properly booting up (probably a confusing desktop configuration that can be replaced by a more mobile friendly one). If you can modify the system you can poke around and compare the state of your device with contents from the OTA or factory image. The goal is to get the phone booting again and have it flash the next OTA update when it is released that may return the device into a pristine condition, though there is no guarantee for that because OTAs are differential updates not complete system images.